# Layout sub folders not getting display in Android studio 3.2 canary build

Tags: android, android-studio

I have started my project in Android studio 3.2 canary latest build(Recently announced in I/O 2018).

My project have sub folder structure for all layout files but with new AS, I am not able to see those folders in Project view nor in Android view in Project tab(Top left tab in android studio)

I have attached screenshots. please check and let me know it is bug or some property have changed.

**Project view**

[image: Project view]

**Android view**

[image: Android view]

**Android view breadcrumbs**

[image: breadcrumbs]

**Gradle file**

```
sourceSets {
    main {
      res.srcDirs =
          [
              'src/main/res/layout/activities',
              'src/main/res/layout/fragments',
              'src/main/res/layout/listitem',
              'src/main/res/layout',
              'src/main/res'
          ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does the project build? If it does, then the issue is Studio-related. If not -- Gradle fails to build the app -- then the issue is tied to your `srcDirs` declaration.

Comment: Yes it compiles and run also from studio.

Comment: All that I can suggest is that you create a scrap project and try to give it the same `res.srcDirs` setup. If that project also exhibits the problem, file an issue with that project as a demonstration.